# suppress warning message and go on loop in r

Tags: r, try-catch

***Update***
solution by ahmohamed

`(lapply(quote_data,is.null))`, and so you can clean your list the same as we cleaned qoute_data by `list_in <- list_in(-which(lapply(quote_data,is.null)))`

**Result**

```
Warning message:
In download.file(url, destfile, method = method, quiet = quiet) :
  only first element of 'url' argument used
```

where

```
getPrice<-function(ticker){
    ticker<-paste(ticker,'ss',sep='.')
    price <- try(get.hist.quote(instrument=ticker,quiet=TRUE, start='2013-01-01',end=Sys.Date()))
    if(class(price) == "try-error") #if error occurred
        price <- NULL
    return(price)
}
```

This simple function where using a getPrice() to download stock price from yahoo, carry a test and filter the suitable data set and save the name in a matrix. I use tryCatch in case of error. The result shown as the bottom. My question is, how can I skip the error and go on finish the loop or as least have the data set "result" where it is cut off?

```
getPrice<-function(ticker){
    ticker<-paste(ticker,'ss',sep='.')
    tryCatch({price<-get.hist.quote(instrument=ticker,start='2013-01-01',end='2015-02-14',quiet=TRUE)})
    return(price)
}
```

then conduct an ADF test, return the test result if data is intact and NULL if not.

```
tts<-function(s1,s2){
    require(fUnitRoots)
    a<-getPrice(s1)[,4]
    b<-getPrice(s2)[,4]
    if (length(a)==length(b)){
    fit<-lm(a~b+0)
    result<-suppressWarnings(adfTest(fit$residuals,type='nc'))
    return(result)
    }
    else return(NULL)
}
```

and here is the loop function

```
screenStock<-function(list_in){

            result<-data.frame()
            n<-0
            for (i in 1:(length(list_in)-1)){
                s1<-getPrice(list_in[i])
                for (j in 2:length(list_in)){
                    s2<-getPrice(list_in[j])
                    adf_T<-tts(s1,s2)
                    if (!is.null(adf_T) && adf_T@test$p.value==0.01){
                        n<-n+1
                        result[n,1]<-list_in[i]
                        result[n,2]<-list_in[j]    
                        result[n,3]<-adf_T@test$statistic}                        
                    }
                }
            return(result) 
        }
```

Well, The result didn't go well.

```
> screenStock(HSlist)
download error, retrying ...
download error, retrying ...
download error, retrying ...
download error, retrying ...
Error in get.hist.quote(instrument = ticker, start = "2013-01-01", end = "2015-02-14",  : 
  cannot open URL 'http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=c("000001", "000002", "000004", "000005", "000006", "000007", "000008", "000009", "000010", "000011", "000012", "000014", "000016", "000017", "000018", "000019", "000020", "000021", "000022", "000023", "000024", "000025", "000026", "000027", "000028", "000029", "000030", "000031", "000032", "000033", "000034", "000035", "000036", "000037", "000039", "000040", "000042", "000043", "000045", "000046", "000048", "000049", "000050", "000055", "000056", "000058", "000059", "000060", "000061", "000062", 
"000063", "000065", "000066", "000068", "000655", "000656", "000659", "000661", "000662", "000663", "000665", "000666", "000667", "000668", "000669", "000671", "000673", "000676", "000677", "000678", "000679", "000680", "000682", "000683", "000685", "000686", "000687", "000690", "000691", "000692", "000695", "000697", "000698", "000700", "000701", "000702", "000703", "000705", "000707", "000708", "000709", "000710", "000711", "0007
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile, method = method, quiet = quiet) :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '0 (nil)'
2: In download.file(url, destfile, method = method, quiet = quiet) :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '0 (nil)'
3: In download.file(url, destfile, method = method, quiet = quiet) :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '0 (nil)'
4: In download.file(url, destfile, method = method, quiet = quiet) :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '0 (nil)'
5: In download.file(url, destfile, method = method, quiet = quiet) :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '0 (nil)'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check if error occurred during the download process. You can accomplish this in *getPrice* function.

```
getPrice<-function(ticker){
    ticker<-paste(ticker,'ss',sep='.')
    price <- try(get.hist.quote(instrument=ticker,start='2013-01-01',end='2015-02-14',quiet=TRUE))
    if(class(price) == "try-error") #if error occurred
        price <- NULL
    return(price)
}
```

Now, *getPrice* will return NULL for errors. You can then check if *s1* or *s2* are NULLs in *tts*

```
if (!is.null(s1) && !is.null(s2) && (length(a)==length(b))){
# Do your test    
}
```

***Note:*** I do not have experience with *get_hist_quote* function, but if it downloads data every time it is called, then you should call *getPrice* function once for all tickers in your list and store the data in a variable for later use. For example,

```
screenStock<-function(list_in){

quote_data <- lapply(list_in, getPrice)
filtered_quote_data <- quote_data[-which(lapply(quote_data,is.null))]

for (i in 1:(length(filtered_quote_data)-1)){
    s1<-filtered_quote_data[i]
         for (j in 2:length(filtered_quote_data)){
                s2<-filtered_quote_data[j]

# Continue your code.
```

Comment: Thank you, it is a great improvement over my orginal code.

Comment: But some how it still can not circumvent the error. The screenStock stop at  the after the first elements in the list. I already knew the "000002" in HSlist would return a error in getPrice()

Comment: This is not a programming problem. The error arises because the url doesn't exist. Even pasting http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=000002  in your browser will give an error.

Comment: You are right. The list contains some ticker that doesn't exist anymore, ie, this is an 'dirty' list. Is there any way to identify and clean the list? ie, recognize the 'doesn't exist error type', then remove the corresponding ticker from the list.

Comment: "dirty" tickers are given in the above code in `which(lapply(quote_data,is.null))`, and so you can clean your list the same as we cleaned `qoute_data` by `list_in <- list_in(-which(lapply(quote_data,is.null)))`

Comment: Thanks to your help. However the bug still persist. See my update.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand which function is generating the warning. Is it `getPrice`. Also, you can modify the code a little bit like this `price <- try(get.hist.quote(instrument=ticker,start='2013-01-01',end='2015-02-14',quiet=TRUE), silent=TRUE)`. Adding `silent=TRUE` can suppress these warnings.

Comment: No worry @admohamed you have been great helpful. It comes from getPrice, and to be exact, it is the get.hist.quote cause the problem. I try to use suppressWarnings and silent=True,or use another function such as getSymbols,it's all stop if the downloading link doesn't work.